# Problem with writing a custome evaluation metric in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to turn the bellow code to a function that would be compatible with tensors instead of NumPy array and I don't know how can I change this! It raises lots of errors and common ways for converting tensors to NumPy arrays don't work for me.

```
#calculation of Rank func
def get_rankMean(y_true,y_pred):
    p = y_pred
    test_count = len(p)
    rank  = 0
    for k in range(test_count):
      temp = np.append(y_pred, [p[k]], axis=0)
      temp = np.array([np.subtract(i, y_true[k]) for i in temp])
      temp = np.square(temp)
      sum = temp.sum(axis = 1)
      arr = np.arange(len(sum))
      arr = np.append([sum], [arr], axis=0)
      arr = arr[ :, arr[0].argsort()]
      rank += np.where(arr[1] == test_count)[0][0]

    rank /= test_count
    #len(p)
    return rank
test=test_y.to_numpy()
predict1=predict[1]
get_rankMean(test,predict1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing in *Eager* mode you can change tensors to numpy by calling their `numpy()` method. If not, you can change your code into tensorflow compatible code (e.g. changing `len(p)` to `tf.shape(p)[0]`).

If you want more help, please change your code in a way that it has all definitions (for example we don't know what are *test_y* or *predict[1]*) and the functions inputs are the tensors you want but you get error.

Comment: This function is a rank for a regression problem. we want to check whether the prediction is random or not! If it is random the rank is not good. we are trying to calculate MSE for all predictions and one true value each time then we sort all these MSE values and check what is the rank of MSE of model's prediction value among all for that specific true value. I hope I explain well!